# Send Notification at a specific time

Tags: android, notifications

I need to, for example, at 1PM to send a notification. how can i do this and repeat it periodically.

I need this code to be implemented with the "repeat code" :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent , 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("Ticker Title")
            .setSmallIcon("icon")
            .setContentTitle("Notification Content Title")
            .setContentText("Output")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Your question is not very descriptive but here is what you can do
1) Create a new Thread, 2) Calculate the time in milliseconds to the Notification Time, 3) Sleep for that amount of time, 4) Do Notification

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 12*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
```

using the notify service and alarm manager you can do the required.

Answer (score 0):

Use alarm manager class to start an intent on your desired time.

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 02);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Here, you need to provide the time at which you want to call the intent. In my code, it is 2AM every night. Also, for repeat interval, I selected a day because my process needed to be called on daily basis.